# Uncaught ReferenceError:React is not defined in bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, bundle

I'm trying to develop a sails app with react as the front end. I have integrated the two using webpack. However nothing is showing up on the browser except the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError:React is not defined at Object(bundle.js:6)

I know a question regarding this has already been asked but none of the suggestions seemed to work for me

Below is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack=require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: './assets/src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/.tmp/public',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
       {
        use: 'babel-loader@^7',
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        test: /\.css$/
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'assets/src/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugins({
      'React':'react',
    }),
  ]
};`
```

My `index.html`:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>`
```

My `index.js`:

```
 import REACT from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import './index.css';
 import 
'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
 import Counter from './components/counter';ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

And my jsx file called `counter.jsx`:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
class Counter extends Component {
    render() { 
        return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question and turns out it was staring at me the whole time. My index.js ought to say :
     import React from 'react'